# How can a SQL row be split into multiple rows based on Boolean?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2016

I have a table with a structure like this, where for each ID, the columns a, b, c, and d have boolean values of True or False:

[image: Original Table]

I am trying to query the table to generate a view where there are only 2 columns (ID and val). I need each row to contain a tuple with an ID and name of the column that had the value of True for that ID. If multiple columns had a True value for that ID, they would be on separate rows, like this:

[image: Desired query output]

I am not sure if this is possible and don't know how to approach this as I have not needed to do something like this in SQL before, but if anyone could give me any helpful tips or guidance that would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Edit: I am trying to do this in MS Access 2016.

Comment: Is the data type of the columns Boolean or VARCHAR? Tag your question with the database that you use.

Comment: The tag wiki for the SQL tag says *Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data, and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used.* Please [edit] your post to provide that information. Your tables and sample data should be in the form of text tables or DDL/DML, so that if needed they can be used to create the tables and populate them.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this:

```
With base as (
  Select id, ‘a’ Val
  From table
  Where a = true
  Union all
  Select id, ‘b’ Val
  From table
  Where b = true
  Union all
  Select id, ‘c’ Val
  From table
  Where c = true
  Union all
  Select id, ‘d’ Val
  From table
  Where d = true
)
Select ID, Val
From base
Order by ID, Val;
```

Let know of questions or thoughts on how it works for you . . .

Answer (score 0):

Try this (for T-SQL):

```
declare 
    @t table (ID int, a varchar(10), b varchar(10), c varchar(10), d varchar(10))

insert into @t
select 1, 'True', 'False', 'False', 'True'
union all
select 2, 'False', 'False', 'True', 'False'
union all
select 3, 'True', 'True', 'True', 'False'
union all
select 4, 'False', 'True', 'False', 'True'


SELECT ID, col, val  
FROM   
    (SELECT ID, a, b, c, d 
    FROM @t) p  
UNPIVOT  
    (val FOR col IN   
        (a, b, c, d)  
)AS unpvt
where val='True'
```